# Changeing view in a SplitViewController using a segmented controll in toolbar of DetailView

Tags: ipad, uisegmentedcontrol, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to change the views (Master and Detail) of my spliviewcontroller using a segmented controll located on a toolbar on the DetailView.

I'm not sure how to controll these views.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to have your segment controller change subviews within these views rather than changing the views themselves.

When the user taps a segment on the segment control, send the action to your DetailViewController and switch out the subview for another one.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  This sounds like it will work perfectly.  I'm having a little bit of trouble with the syntax can you point me to an example?  Everything that I am trying is either giving me an error or doesn't do anything.

Thanks again.

Comment: There are many ways to do it.  Try posting a specific example of what you have tried that is not working?